# Multiple Header - "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" need to be set - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cors, cross-domain

I am working on  an MVC application(Controller methods with JSONRESULT) which will be accessed by couple of other application running on other domains using HttpClient / $.ajax.So I require to enable cross-domain calls. I know that only 1 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is allowed on response, so I am trying to dynamically set this response header using Custom ActionFilterAttribute and Custom-HttpModule. But none of these works if requests is coming from $.ajax or Javascript app. Please help me here.

Note :  It works only if I set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" from web.config. But unfortunately I cant set multiple domains here. Sorry, in my scenario I cant use wildcard for this header, since the requester need to pass withCredentials: true on their $.ajax request and need to keep session id same .

Comment: how about "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" ? for allowing all domains?

Comment: I tried that, but on $ajax request I need to set "withCredentials: true" for "xhrFields", This  will not allow wildcard on "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" . I am setting this to true  because I need session id to be same for all to this application from the same browser instance...

Comment: @sumit, or else could you please tell me some idea to keep session id same for the requests coming from a browser instance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your question, but in essence this is what you can do:
1. Call the webservice from your back-end rather than your front-end (you won't need to set any headers in that case.
2. Add the headers you mentioned from a filter which would apply them to all responses.

Why I say that I don't understand your question:

> But none of these works if requests is coming from $.ajax or
>   Javascript app.

These headers must be set when coming from server to client, not from client to server.

Comment: Yes, I am setting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" from server side on response using a custom actionfilterattribute. But on the client side, its giving me an error "Origin 'https://requestor' not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header"

Comment: Ah, this is something else. Have you also included the header for OPTIONS request type?

Comment: Yes. Could you please tell anything else I need to check ?  Also, You know, I have added "xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }," to make session id same for every request from the same browser. But this setting is not working with  wildcard setting on Access-Control-Allow-Origin